# Always inject some fields in a Spring service through the context

Tags: java, spring, initialization, code-injection, applicationcontext

I've got the following class:

```
@Service
public class TestService{

    @Autowired
    private Integer size;

    private MyClass myObject;

    public Test(){
        // Default constructor for Spring
    }

    public Test(MyClass myObject){
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    // Getters and Setters ...

}
```

Now I'm instantiating my `TestService` from outside this class with

```
new TestService(myObject);
```

The variable `size` is of course `null`. But I want it to be injected from the spring context even though I didn't inject the whole object.

Is it possible to always inject some fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [static AspectJ compilation (or load time weaving) and `@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable): any Object with the `@Configurable` annotation will be autowired, even when instantiated through `new()`

But the more traditional way would be to wire it up programatically:

```
MyBean foo = new MyBean();
ApplicationContext ctx = // whereever you get your context from
ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put an arbitrary object through the autowiring process using:

```
appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(existingBean)
```

You still need a reference to the `appContext` to do this, though, which is up to you.

The fancier way is to use load-time weaving, using AspectJ and `@Configurable`, but this takes more configuration effort - see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible. Only the objects that spring instantiates are the ones that it manages the lifecycle of. I mean Spring has no way to know that you instantiated that object. May be if it hooked to the JVM itself it can do that but it doesnt. And philosophically its not how IoC is written and will be written.

Comment: "if it hooked to the JVM itself it can do that but it doesnt" - it can do - using `@Configurable` (see other answers)

Comment: Its not Spring's job. Its AspectJ's job. Spring is a DI framework. Its called weaving and Spring doesnt do that

Comment: a) Spring is one of the largest contributors to AspectJ, e.g. Ramnivas Laddad, author of AspectJ in Action is a Spring Committer b) We are talking about aspects and annotations that belong to the official Spring distribution. This *is* part of Spring

Comment: Thats great. Spring supports AspectJ annotations it has great support to do AOP but Spring is majorly a DI framework and its not the right way to write them. More over Spring's AOP uses runtime weaving and not load time weaving or compile time weaving...

Comment: a) Spring is [a lot more than a DI system](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules) b) both [AspectJ](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) and [`@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ajlib-other) are explicitly described in the Spring reference as alternatives to Spring AOP. There's always more than one way to do it, and especially in Spring.